# How to check on which port apache is running

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

Is there any command to find out if apache is running or not.

and on which port except by seeingports.conf files

When i try netstat command then apaches does not appear in that.

but when i use apache2 restart command then it says restart ok

i don't know where it is running

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`lsof -i` list open ports and the corresponding applications.

For a general check if an app is running you could just use `ps aux | grep apache2`

Comment: Or "ps aux | grep httpd" for redhat/centos.

Answer (score 28):

```
netstat -anp | grep apache
```

You could see the listening port and PID from this if it's running.

Comment: sudo netstat -anp | grep apache

Comment: It's showing 0.0.0.0:80 in the "Local Address" column. Does it mean apache is running at the same ip address of the machine, on port 80?

Comment: try this `netstat -anp | grep -E 'State|java|solr|apache|php|nginx`

Answer (score 6):

```
netstat -tulpn
```

You'll see the Pid / Binary name on far right column, match this to your running apache instance.

Answer (score 3):

If lsof is installed you could try something like this:

```
lsof | grep httpd
```

(for centos and friends)

```
lsof  | grep apache
```

(for debian and company)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the port number then run

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep apache | awk 'NR==1{print $4}' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}'
```

Comment: Only answer that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For FreeBSD:

```
sockstat | grep apache httpd
```